# TinyMCE - Increase number of characters in summary

Tags: tinymce

is there a way to unlock the restrictions of number of characters in the summary field of the TinyMCE editor?

Found only solutions how to do the exact opposite.

Currently it is limited to 30 characters in the summary field.

Thank you for your help.

Comment: TinyMCE has no concept of a "summary field".  Are you using TinyMCE in some sort of CMS or other platform?  Are you referring to some dialog withing TinyMCE?  If so you should update the question with those details.

Answer (score 0):

OK, turns out that it was not a TinyMCE problem, but a Java controller setting...